# Blender eevee everything looks foggy

Tags: rendering

I have no idea why it happens, I open a old 2.79 file in the blender 2.82, and it looks like that

[image: object render looks foggy in eevee]
[image: object looks fade out when camera far from center]

I found that if I change the volumetrics end to very low it seems solved, but I dont think that's the correct way to solve that, something must be wrong in other place

[image]
[image]

Finally I found that I use volume scattering in cycles and that caused the condition

[image]

Comment: Please use the answer section to add an answer.